# App Rejected on Play store with Issue: Violation of Permissions policy (App sending SMS on Button Click)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console

I know My question is duplicate but the scenario is different.So I'm working on app which sends sms on button click to a device which is connected to a gate to open or shut the gate depends on the sms we send through app with specific format in the body.
So I'm asking permission from user to `SEND_SMS`. And When I upload to play store before Rolling out to Production is shows an Error regarding the privacy.I submitted thrice with different options like `Default SMS Handler` and `Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls` but every time its rejected by Google.Here is their response through Email.

> Issue: Violation of Permissions policy After reviewing your app, we
> found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the
> following reason(s): Requested permissions do not match core
> functionality of the app You declared Cross-device synchronization or
> transfer of SMS or calls as the core functionality of your app.
> However, after review, we found that your app does not match the
> declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.
> Please either: • Make changes to your app so that it meets the
> requirements of the declared core functionality or, • Select a use
> case that matches your app’s functionality

Can Anybody help me out how to cop with this to publish it successfully.I don't want to use `react-native-sms` to get user interaction to send sms through `SMS APP`

Comment: How can just sending an sms beeing a core activity of a normal app?

Comment: its not but we don't have any other option to select.What we can do then